# Add class 'active' when hovering over an element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

Here is example -> [codepen](http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/rbJpu)

My question is how to do active `class="active"` that hover function wont aply for this button with `class="active"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this line:

```
$("nav ul li a").hover(function(){
```

like this:

```
$("nav ul li a:not(.active)").hover(function(){
```

See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ehosj

Comment: omg that was so easy, i just made fool of myself :). Thank you mate.